# Different behaviour between docker-compose volume mount on OSX and Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have some frustration on mounting data containers with docker.

I got this example docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  code:
    image: cogniteev/echo
    command: echo 'Data Container for App Code'
    volumes:
     - ./data/:/data/
  server:
    image: debian:jessie
    volumes_from:
     - code
```

And it works perfectly on OSX. When i am running `docker-compose run server ls /data` i see my host data structure.
But when i am trying to do same on my debian server i don't see any of /data content mounted in `server` container.

What am i doing wrong?
Docker server version 1.10.3 on OSX and debian server.

UPD:
Even example from Docker Docs `docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash` not working properly

Comment: do you have ./data directory on debian server?

Comment: @Cortwave yes i have

Answer (score 0):

does this work ...

```
volumes:
    - ./data:/data # mount data dir on host inside container
    - /data # mount data dir inside container to other containers
```

?